# Ricci Scalar of the five-dimensiional Reissner–Nordström metric is different to zero?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, curvature

The Ricci scalar of the four-dimensional [Reissner–Nordström metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric) is equal to zero. In the case of the five-dimensional Reissner–Nordström metric, the Ricci scalar is different to zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The electromagnetic field is nonzero, so the stress-energy tensor is equal to $\frac{1}{2}F_{ac}F^{c}{}_{b}- \frac{1}{8}g_{ab}F^{cd}F_{cd}$.  And, of course, $8\pi G T_{ab} = R_{ab} -\frac{1}{2}Rg_{ab}$

EDIT: to clarify, in the riessner-Nordstrom spacetime, you have $g_{ab} = {\rm diag} (-\Delta, \frac{1}{\Delta}, {\rm sphere\; metric})$ and $F_{ab} = f(r)\left(dtdr - drdt\right)$.  Meanwhile, you contract Einstein's equation, and you get $$R - (d/2)R = 8\pi G\left(\frac{1}{2}F^{ab}F_{ab} - (d/8)F^{ab}F_{ab}\right)$$

Therefore, you get

$$R = \frac{2\pi G(4-d)}{2-d}F^{ab}F_{ab}$$

So, ALL electrovac solutions have a vanishing ricci scalar in four dimensions only.  In higher dimensions $F_{ab} \neq 0$, so $R\neq 0$

Comment: @JuanOspina, then you need to calculate it.  You certainly shouldn't expect a zero Ricci scalar in either case.  The stress-energy tensor is nonzero.

Comment: And seriously, your question just involves going and doing some math.  Just do the math.

Comment: but, there, see the edit, @JuanOspina

Comment: @JuanOspina: why?  the exterior derivative is definied in all dimensions, and it adds only one index in all dimensions.  $F_{ab}$ is an antisymmetric 2-tensor in all dimensions.

Comment: @ Jerry Schirme.  The reason is that the solution of three-dimensional Laplace equation for the electrostatic potential is of the form $C/r$ and the electromagnetic field is $C/r^2$; but in four spatial dimensions the solution for the corresponding Laplace equation takes the form $C/r^2$ and the electromagnetic field has the form $C/r^3$. At general in $d$ spatial dimensions the potential has the form $C/r^{d-2}$ and the electromagnetic field has the form $C/r^{d-1}$.  Do you agree?

Comment: @JuanOspina, Oh, I forgot that I explicitly listed the form of the maxwell tensor.  Sure.  YOu're right.

Comment: @ JerrySchirme: now all is correct.  Again, many thanks.  All the best.